# Why is it b=1 not b=-1?

Tags: java

my professor gave us this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class Problem1{
 public static void main( String[] args ){
 int a=5, b=6, c=1;
 double x=0.5, y=1.0, z=1.5;
 c = fcn1(a, b);
 y = fcn2(y, a);
 b = fcn3(x, y);
 z = fcn3(c, b);
 System.out.println("a="+a+", b="+b+", c="+c);
 System.out.println("x="+x+", y="+y+", z="+z);
 }
 static int fcn1(int i, int j){
 int k = i-j;
 return (++k);
 }
 static double fcn2(double t, int n){
 return (t*n);
 }
 static int fcn3(double u, double v){
 return fcn1((int)(u*v), 2);
 }
 static double fcn3(int r, int s){
 return fcn2(r,s);
 }
}
```

and when you run it, the output is:

```
a=5, b=1, c=0
x=0.5, y=5.0, z=0.0
```

I did not understand why b=1 so I made a separate file just to solve for b:

```
class p1 {
 public static void main(String [] args){
  int a=5, b=6, c=1;
  double x=0.5, y=1.0, z=1.5;
  b= fcn3(x,y);
  System.out.println("b="+b);
  }
  static int fcn1(int i, int j){
   int k = i-j;
   return (++k);
  }

  static int fcn3(double u, double v){
   return fcn1((int)(u*v), 2);
  }
}
```

and when I run this, I get b=-1 
I don't understand, help?

Comment: What makes you think it should be `-1`?

Comment: (0.5 * 1.0)  = 0.5 truncates to 0 when you apply (int).  Inside fcn1: 0-2=-2 and ++ makes it -1.

Comment: Your first and second programs compute `b` differently. Your first one recomputes `y` with `y = fcn2(y, a)` before calling `b = fcn3(x, y)`. But your second program doesn't do that. So I wouldn't expect them to yield the same results for `b`.

Comment: Code is also kind of stupid, maybe on purpose, e.g. for fcn1 you could just write `return i - j + 1;` incrementing a variable you never use makes no sense. And fnc3 would be `return (int) (u * v) - 1;`

Comment: Did you noticed that `y` gets new value with `y = fcn2(y, a)` which is executed before `b = fcn3(x, y);`?

Comment: I strongly recommend stepping through this with a debugger.  I can guarantee, the answer will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In your professor code, y = fcn2(y, a); y becomes 5 and in your source code, value of y = 1.0

```
//Professor Code
//Initial value y= 1.0, but after this line

**y = fcn2(y, a);**
```

[image]
    [image]

```
 //y = 5;

b = fcn3(x, y);   //y = 5;
```

//Your Code

```
b = fcn3(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fcn3(), you pass .5 and 1, and multiply them, that is .5, then you cast it to an int which drops it to 0, so fcn1() gets 0 and 2, 0-2 = -2, 1+-2 = -1 which is finally assigned to b.

Comment: but why is the output b=1 not b=-1?

Comment: @xnino, `y = fcn2(y, a);` means `y = 1.0 * 5` or `y = 5.0`, followed by `b = fcn3(x, y)` which means `b = fcn3(0.5, 5.0)` which is `fcn1((int)(0.5 * 5.0), 2)` which is `fcn1(2, 2)` (because the `(int)` cast truncates), which leads to `k = 2 - 2 = 0` and the `return ++k` returns 1. So `b = 1`.